# wso2 bam2.4 connect to external cassandra failed by .AuthenticationException

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I think I have followed all the examples what I can find, 
and I am working on bam2.4.1, the apache cassandra is 2.1.2.

I have configured casandra to disable security by setting cassandra.yaml
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

Then I follow  bam2.4.1 document to connect to external cassandra, then start wso2 bam by 
wso2server.bat -Ddisable.cassandra.server.startup=true

All most everything works except authentication

```
[2014-11-25 20:39:41,295] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.Notificat
ionDispatchTask} -  Error executing notification dispatch task: Access denied fo
r user wso2bam to login TCP,192.168.1.7:7611,TCP,192.168.1.7:7711
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: Access den
ied for user wso2bam to login TCP,192.168.1.7:7611,TCP,192.168.1.7:7711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authentica
tor.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.start(DataPubli
sher.java:273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPubl
isher.java:211)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.NotificationDispatchTask.initPu
blisherKS(NotificationDispatchTask.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.NotificationDispatchTask.execut
e(NotificationDispatchTask.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuar
tzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentAuthenticatorE
xception: Thrift exception
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authentica
tor.ThriftAgentAuthenticator.connect(ThriftAgentAuthenticator.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authentica
tor.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:51)
        ... 12 more
```

I found some more exception like

```
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketExcep
tion: Connection closed by remote host
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTranspo
rt.java:147)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeI32(TBinaryProtocol.j
ava:163)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeMessageBegin(TBinaryP
rotocol.java:91)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecure
EventTransmissionService$Client.send_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionServic
e.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecure
EventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.jav
a:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authentica
tor.ThriftAgentAuthenticator.connect(ThriftAgentAuthenticator.java:47)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:70)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTranspo
rt.java:145)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: You shouldn't format the exception like this. You can copy the exception as it's and use code formatter here. This is not readable

Comment: I found the bam2.4.1 still uses libthrift-0.7.0wos2v2.jar. Is is possible that this jar cannot work with cassandra 2.1.2?